# Pandas Adding Column Maximum to the Original Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe below where I want to get the maximum of individual columns:

```
       A      B      C      D
0  0.191 -0.191  0.227 -0.607
1 -0.227 -0.418  0.418 -0.416
2  0.607  0.416  0.835 -0.835
```

I guess I can loop through all the columns and store the maximum else where. Just wonder if by any chance this can be handle by pandas/numpy manipulation

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Use `df.max()` ?

Comment: Or `df['max'] = df.max(axis=1)` ?